# C# How to make a list of Dictionaries into array

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a method which accept params of Dictionary

```
static IDictionary<double, double> Merge(params Dictionary<double, double>[] dicts)
{
    return dicts.SelectMany(p => p).ToLookup(p => p.Key, p => p.Value)
                                   .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Max());
}
```

I can use `var r = Merge(r1,r2,r3);` and it will work fine. r1,r2,r3 are dictionaries.
The problem is I don't know the number of Dictionaries I have, it fluctuates , sometimes 3, sometimes 30, or 300. I have the dictionaries in a list. Actualy I have a list of a class. so somehow I have to make it work in a foreach loop?

```
List<Class1> c = new List<Class1>();

class Class1
    {
        public Dictionary<Double, Double> r1 = new Dictionary<Double, Double>();
    }
```

Comment: _"How to make a list of Dictionaries into a “string”"_? How is the title related to your question?

Comment: @JohnRyann i changed my answer to fit your update!

Answer (score 3):

You have a method that accepts an array of dictionaries, so you only need to turn your list into an array.

```
var result = Merge(listOfDictionaries.ToArray());
```

Comment: this may iterate listOfDictionaries, which is not good for performance!

Comment: @esskar The number of dictionaries has already been mentioned to be small.  This is by no means a performance issue.  The list would need to have millions or billions of items for it to even matter a little bit.  For it to matter a *lot* it likely wouldn't fit into memory.  This is simply the wrong place to try to optimize.  Downvoting an answer for such a trivial microoptimization is pretty absurd.

Comment: if you call that multiple times it will decrease performance. You do not know where the code is run (neither do I).

Comment: @esskar The operation itself is orders of magnitude more expensive than this operation would be.  For this to be called enough to have any measurable difference the amount of merging being done would need to be pretty huge, and that would very likely be a strong sign of improper design, as merging all of N different data structures is an inherently expensive operation.  If he really is doing it a lot (which I doubt) it's a sign that he should be redesigning his code to *not* call it so frequently because copying the dictionaries from a list to array would be the least of his problems.

Comment: @Servy my listOfDIctionaries is actualy a list of classes which have dictionary. How to do this?

Comment: @JohnRyann Then project that list into a sequence of dictionaries.  There is a LINQ operator specifically for performing such projections.

Comment: @Servy, you marked my other question as duplicate to this. Can you be fair and answer my question?

Answer (score 2):

after the original question was edited, now a update that should fix your problem. The new function merge takes an IEnumerable of `Class1` and merges it to a `Dictionary`. It uses the `Merge(IEnumerable<Dictionary<double, double>> dicts)` the is defined below:

```
 static Dictionary<Double, Double> Merge(IEnumerable<Class1> classes)
 {
     return Merge(classes.Select(c => c.r1));
 }
```

**Original Answer**:

a small change in your parameter type definition should do it

```
static IDictionary<double, double> Merge(IEnumerable<Dictionary<double, double>> dicts)
{
    return dicts.SelectMany(p => p)
        .ToLookup(p => p.Key, p => p.Value)
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Max());
}
```

now you can just pass a list of dictionaries

**EDIT**
If you want to use both variations, you can do this like this

```
static IDictionary<double, double> Merge(params Dictionary<double, double>[] dicts)
{
    return Merge((IEnumerable<Dictionary<double, double>>)dicts);
}
```

Comment: This inhibits the use of the method when the number of parameters *is* known at compile time.  If this is done it should likely be as an additional overload rather than as a replacement of the method itself.

Comment: fixed that in a hint.

Comment: Also, you're edit is incorrect; as it is accepting a sequence of sequences of dictionarys, which is incorrect.